# how to merge two audios files by the using FFmpeg with special condition?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg

I have a special issue. Maybe not :D

I have two audios files. First of all. The first audio file has been changed just hear the right side of the headphone. Because of I used that FFmpeg command.

```
ffmpeg -i fisrt.wav -af “an=stereo|c1=c1” outr.wav
```

Then, Second audio file has been changed just hear the left side of the headphone. I used this command.

```
ffmpeg -i second.wav -af “pan=stereo|c0=c0” outl.wav
```

**Problem**

I want to merge these files with the special condition. This condition is the first audio/outr.wav/ is just heard the right side of the headphone. Then, second audio/outl.wav/ is just heard the left side of the headphone. So, I tried this command.

```
ffmpeg -i left.mp3 -i right.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a][1:a]amerge=inputs=2[a]" -map "[a]" output.wav
```

Unfortunately, this result is don't want. The result hears both sides of headphone with different volume.

Can you help me, please?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Downmix each input into specific output channel

[image: Downmix each input into specific output channel]

You can do everything in one command using the [amerge](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amerge) and [pan](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pan) filters:

```
ffmpeg -i fisrt.wav -i second.wav -filter_complex "[0][1]amerge=inputs=2,pan=stereo|FL<c0+c1|FR<c2+c3[a]" -map "[a]" output.wav
```

- This example assumes both inputs are stereo.
- See [FFmpeg Wiki: Audio Channels](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation) for more info.